# how to embed a code editor in a page?

Tags: javascript, python

Problem

```
I want to create a page with a code editor embedded in it.I looked up codemirror
but i am having problems using it as i am new to java script.
```

So I am looking for an easy way to embed a code editor into a page(using java script or python).Can someone please provide
some link/tutorial or method for it.

Comment: Stupidly, the formatting cannot be fixed because the site now prohibits the title which this was posted with.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try Ace: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace (source) https://ace.c9.io/ (Project page), this JavaScript editor is used by Cloud9

Comment: Trunecek It was quite helpful, but I have having bit problems understanding some inbuilt commands , can you give some link to its documentation

Comment: On their page is all you need (I guess) API reference is here: http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=api, How-To guide here: http://ace.ajax.org/#nav=howto. If you have concrete problem, try to ask here (new question) or via comment and I will try to answer you. Have a nice day

Answer (score 10):

I know this is old post , 
This is how i did while developing online code-editor
you can use ace-editor

check this sample from ace

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>ACE in Action</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    #editor { 
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="editor">function foo(items) {
    var x = "All this is syntax highlighted";
    return x;
}</div>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.5/ace.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit("editor");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9):

There is another embeddable JavaScript code editor: [CodeJar](https://medv.io/codejar/)

It's just **2 kB** and has great features in it.

```css
.editor {
    color: #fff;
    background: #282a36;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    font-family: monospace;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 400;
    min-height: 240px;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    tab-size: 4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CodeJar</title>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.20.0/themes/prism-twilight.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="editor language-js">function fibonacci(n) {
 let num;

 if (n >= 2) {
  num = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
 } else {
  num = n
 }

 return num;
}</div>

<script type="module" id="code">
  import {CodeJar} from "https://medv.io/codejar/codejar.js?"

  const jar = new CodeJar(
    document.querySelector(".editor"), 
    Prism.highlightElement
  )
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.20.0/components/prism-core.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.20.0/plugins/autoloader/prism-autoloader.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```