# WYSIWYG javascript editor with page support

Tags: wysiwyg, wysihtml5

I'm looking for an WYSIWYG editor with page support (similar to word).
Extensibility would also be nice.

Can be a commercial solution as well.

---

Edit: Sorry about the ambiguation. By page support, I need an editor that will show me the pages as they would look like when the document that's edited will be printed out. I need page separation.
All solutions I found so far (ckEditor, tinyMCE) all do a great job at letting the user edit HTML, but they don't support this page separation.

---

Edit 2: This is something close to what I need, the problem is they are doing heavy server side processing, and have a really poor client side API: https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxRichEditDemos/EditingFeatures/TextWithImages.aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by wysiwyg in this context; in terms of *what you see* are you expecting it to be the javascript code, or the results thereof? I'm also not sure what you mean by "page support" -- are you just looking for a word processor with javascript scripting?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguation. I'm looking for an HTML embeddable edtor (like ckeditor, tinymce) that also can show pages. Just like Word does. Page as it will look like when printed.

Comment: Is the accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064681/how-to-embed-a-code-editor-in-a-page) any good to you? I'm still not sure what you mean by "pages like word does" because code isn't paginated (in fact paginating code makes it harder to read and follow imho).

Comment: Are you asking for somthing like [this](http://www.wiris.com/editor);