# Unable to write R/Python code from our JS applicaiton

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-editor

I'm trying to integrate a code editor within our javascript application to execute R and Python code. 
The ones we have used are just plain vanilla, i'm looking for a code-editor that can provide code highlighting etc and can display results back in another form

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_. See [help].

Comment: @Jonasw the OP is probably asking about a front-end embeddable code editor

Comment: Yes I am asking for the same. However, most of my search gives my browser based code editors and not editors which I can embed in my JS application

Comment: `Try Ace: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace (source) http://ace.ajax.org/ (Project page), this JavaScript editor is used by Cloud9`

Thx to: @JakubTruneček

Answer was found in a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17064681/how-to-embed-a-code-editor-in-a-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this Markdown. More info here:
https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/